# How to reduce the size of picture on the background?

Tags: css

I have a picture size: 240px/240px. This size of picture must be only on wide screens, on mobile this picture must be 80px/80px.
What I have ever tried:

```
.picture{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 240px;        
    background: url("../../img/picture.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) .picture {
    height: 80px;
    transform:scale(.3);
}
```

But this scale parents block, bg scaled wrong, exactly right, but that's not what I need. It's just crops bg-picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set fixed background image, this is example to scale and align your background image:

```css
.pic-wrap {
  display: block;
  height: 296px;
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/590966305248784384/1gX6-SY6_400x400.jpg);
  background-size: 256px;
  background-position: 20px 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 296px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .pic-wrap {
    background-size: 96px;
    height: 126px;
    padding-left: 126px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrap">
  <span class="label">Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: it's near that I need. All problem was in background-size: cover; Now I use  background-size: 100%; on the wide screen and  background-size: 25%; on mobile. And it perfect. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `{}` brackets for media query:

```
.picture{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 240px;        
    background: url("../../img/picture.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
   }


  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /* here */
      .picture {
       height: 80px;
       transform:scale(.3);
      }
  } /* here */
```

Comment: no. brackets are present, I wrote this code (not copy).

Comment: [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Leb5f3a6) is that problem which I have, bg crop when you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
.picture{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 240px;        
    background: url("../../img/picture.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .picture {
      height: 80px;
      min-height: none;
      transform:scale(.3);
  }
}
```